# Parsing two formats of log messages in LogStash

Tags: logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

In a single log file, there are two formats of log messages. First as so:

```
Apr 22, 2017 2:00:14 AM org.activebpel.rt.util.AeLoggerFactory info
INFO:
======================================================
ActiveVOS 9.* version Full license.
Licensed for All application server(s), for 8 cpus,
License expiration date: Never.
======================================================
```

and second:

```
Apr 22, 2017 2:00:14 AM org.activebpel.rt.AeException logWarning
WARNING: The product license does not include Socrates.
```

First line is same, but on the other lines, there can be (written in pseudo) :
`loglevel: <msg>`, or
 `loglevel:<newline><many of =><newline><multiple line msg><newline><many of =>`

I have the following configuration:
Query:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_MW_ERR:timestamp} %{DATA:logger} %{GREEDYDATA:info}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}:(%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:msg}|%{SPACE}=+(%{GREEDYDATA:msg}%{SPACE})*=+)
```

Grok patterns:

```
AMPM (am|AM|pm|PM|Am|Pm)
TIMESTAMP_MW_ERR %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY}, %{YEAR} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} %{AMPM}
```

Multiline filter:

```
%{LOGLEVEL}|%{GREEDYDATA}|=+
```

The problem is that all messages are always identified with `%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:msg}`, and so in second case return `<many of =>` as `msg`, and never with `%{SPACE}=+(%{GREEDYDATA:msg}%{SPACE})*=+`, probably as first `msg` pattern contains the second.

How can I parse these two patterns of `msg` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by following:
Query:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_MW_ERR:timestamp} %{DATA:logger} %{DATA:info}\s%{LOGLEVEL:level}:\s((=+\s%{GDS:msg}\s=+)|%{GDS:msg})
```

Patterns:

```
AMPM (am|AM|pm|PM|Am|Pm)
TIMESTAMP_MW_ERR %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY}, %{YEAR} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} %{AMPM}
GDS (.|\s)*
```

Multiline pattern:

```
%{LOGLEVEL}|%{GREEDYDATA}
```

Logs are correctly parsed.